# How to save list, dict, int into file, and assign back from file

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, format

I have an PYQT5 UI with that allow user to store values into list, int, and qttextedit (allow user to write as code editor.
Then i save existing values into txt file, so after user changed values can always come back and reload from the local file. The problem i face is when i assign back, it became a letter by letter, even the code assign back into UI will have \n. I also tried turn them into a list, but result still bad.
So i think save into a txt is a bad idea, I looked for pickle but not sure if it can be used or how to use in this case.

```
score = 22
ocount = 88
scenario = {something here already}
...
usercode = 'var game = 0;\n if (game > 3){gid = 22}'

#List, int, dict, str store to txt file
with open(configName + ".txt", 'w') as f:
                f.write(repr(score) + "\n" + \
                    repr(ocount) + "\n" + \
                    repr(option) + "\n" + \
                    repr(option_ans) + "\n" + \
                    repr(matchname) + "\n" + \
                    repr(scenario) + "\n" + \
                    repr(_Options) + "\n" + \
                    repr(_Optionselected) + "\n" + \
                    repr(eInfo) + "\n" + \
                    repr(sVar) + "\n" + \
                    repr(cusotm) + "\n" + \
                    repr(survey1) + "\n" + \
                    repr(survey_ans) + "\n" + \
                    repr(eInfoName) + "\n" + \
                    repr(sVarName) + "\n" + \
                    repr(tempcode) + "\n" + \
                    repr(usercode))
```

The value output as below:

```
2
1
['q1_a1', 'q1_a2', 'q2_a1']
['q1_a1_ans', 'q1_a2_ans', 'q2_a1_ans']
['log1', 'log2']
{'log1': 'if (q1_a1) scores.team1 - 1q1_a1_ans== "23234"){\nproduct_ids = [11,22];\n}', 'log2': 'if (scores.team2 != 11\nproduct_ids = [33,2];\n}'}
['var q1_a1 = 11;', 'var q1_a2 = 11122;', 'var q2_a1 = 2;']
['var q1_a1_ans = 22;', 'var q1_a2_ans = 222;', 'var q2_a1_ans = 2;']
['123']
['321']
['cam1']
['q1_a1', 'q1_a2', 'q2_a1']
['q1_a1_ans', 'q1_a2_ans', 'q2_a1_ans']
['123']
['321']
'+ + \nelse if (\nelse if (\nelse if (\nelse if ('
'var has_answer = function (answer) {\n        return indexOf(answer) >= 0;\n    };'
```

```
#Load back

tmp=[]
f = open("lo.txt", "r")
Lines = f.readlines()
for x in Lines:
    tmp.append(x)
score = tmp[0]
ocount = tmp[1]
etc...
```

Result:

```
#try change to list
['[', "'", 'q', '1', '_', 'a', '1', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 'q', '1', '_', 'a', '2', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 'q', '2', '_', 'a', '1', "'", ']', '\n']
```

[image: try add back to UI combobox]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use exec() to execute string as code

```
var = ['score', 'option', 'tempcode', 'usercode']
f = open("lo.txt", "r")
Lines = f.readlines()

for i in range(0, len(Lines)):
    exec(f'{var[i]} = {Lines[i]}')


    # check type
    exec(f'print({var[i]}, type({var[i]}))')
```

output

```
2 <class 'int'>
['q1_a1', 'q1_a2', 'q2_a1'] <class 'list'>
+ + 
else if (
else if (
else if (
else if ( <class 'str'>
var has_answer = function (answer) {
        return indexOf(answer) >= 0;
    }; <class 'str'>
```

lo.txt

```
2
['q1_a1', 'q1_a2', 'q2_a1']
'+ + \nelse if (\nelse if (\nelse if (\nelse if ('
'var has_answer = function (answer) {\n        return indexOf(answer) >= 0;\n    };'
```

Or write them in json instead, make sure list is still list.

Comment: Thx for answer, but im looking for a way to correclty sotre to local, and efficient way to re-assign then.

Comment: Edited my ans, this might work.